# What does "Decloak: (Mac Address)" mean in Airodump-ng

Tags: networking, mac-address, ubuntu

I have Reaver 1.4 on Ubuntu 14.10 and a Realtek RTL8187SE B/G adapter, and I got a message saying: "Decloak: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (the X's would be letters and number of the MAC Address). What does this mean?

Comment: Have you done any research? I've found a bunch of hits using a Google search.

Comment: Yes. It says that it means that the network is hidden, but the network manager can catch it.

Comment: So, do you have your answer, or where are you on this problem right now?